# Configuration error: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I have developed a web application using c# and asp.net but when I am trying to publish and put it into the server using ftp then I am getting this following error:

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration
 file required to service this request. Please review the specific error 
 details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as 
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error 
can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application 
in IIS.

```
Source File: \\fs8-n02\stor10wc2dfw1\555713\570520\www.gxxxxjjsxx.ssd\web\content\2way\armb
              \web.config    Line: 9
```

Here if I check on my Line 9 of the web config file then I get this:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
```

And here is my complete web config file code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>

     <configuration>
     <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolKit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have checked whether I have multiple web config files but I could not find something like that. And also I have used this published folder into my IIS and I can browse the site from my localhost using IIS but still when ever I am trying to browse using the [link](http://projects.globalsms.ae/2way/armb):

I am getting the same error. Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using applications under a site in IIS?  Given the source file path what is the root project folder?  \\fs8-n02\stor10wc2dfw1\555713\570520\www.gxxxxjjsxx.ssd\web\content\2way\armb

Comment: yes it is the root project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem: Actually the path was not configured properly into the IIS as a virtual directory. So, that I had to create a proper virtual directory and then only I am able to access the site.